# Snowflake queries are not returning timezone information

Tags: ruby, jdbc, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Timestamp values with a timezone element are not returned correctly when queried using Snowflake JDBC & Ruby ODBC Drivers.

Is there a way where we can add additional library to get the Zone information in the Resultset when the datatype is of type timestamp_ltz, timestamp_ntz,timestamp_tz in Snowflake.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import net.snowflake.client.core.QueryStatus;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeResultSet;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatement;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.*;

public class SnowFlakeIntegration {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:snowflake://mysnowflakeacc.snowflakecomputing.com?allowMultiQueries=true";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("user", "query_user");
        prop.put("password", "mypassword");
        prop.put("role", "myrole");

        try (Connection conn = getConnection(url, prop)) {
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            String query2 = "select Now() as now_function, at_timezone(Now(),'America/Denver') as denver, at_timezone(Now(),'Asia/Kolkata') as India;";
            ResultSet resultSet = stat.unwrap(SnowflakeStatement.class).executeAsyncQuery(query2);
            QueryStatus queryStatus = QueryStatus.RUNNING;
            while (queryStatus == QueryStatus.RUNNING) {
                Thread.sleep(200); // 2000 milliseconds.
                queryStatus = resultSet.unwrap(SnowflakeResultSet.class).getStatus();
            }
            System.out.println(queryStatus);
            if (queryStatus != QueryStatus.FAILED_WITH_ERROR) {
                if (queryStatus != QueryStatus.SUCCESS) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: unexpected QueryStatus: " + queryStatus);
                } else {
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
                    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                    ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        int numColumns = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
                            String column_name = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i);
                            obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
                        }
                        json.add(obj);
                    }
                    System.out.println(json);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format(
                        "ERROR %d: %s%n", queryStatus.getErrorMessage(), queryStatus.getErrorCode());
            }
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[{"NOW_FUNCTION":2021-02-24 16:16:19.642,"DENVER":2021-02-24 04:46:19.642,"INDIA":2021-02-24 04:46:19.642}]
```

The Same Query When executed from Snowflake Console or DB returns the correct value with ZOne information

[image]

Comment: To add some more context: What is your `Now()` UDF returning? Also, looks like you have another custom `at_timezone` function... why do you need either of these? why not use the standard SQL functions that snowflake provide to do these?

Comment: What version of the Snowflake JDBC driver are you using? I don't see a class in the JAR for net.snowflake.client.core.QueryStatus in the latest, which is 3.9.2.

Comment: we are using snowflake-jdbc version 3.13.0

Comment: `THE UDF Function now()  RETURNS TIMESTAMP_LTZ(5)  AS 'current_timestamp(5)';`

Comment: `THE UDF FUNCTION at_timezone(a_timestamp TIMESTAMP, target_timezone VARCHAR) RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS 'convert_timezone(target_timezone, public.current_timezone(), a_timestamp)::TIMESTAMP';`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to return timestamp with timezone information, your UDF functions should return timestamp with timezone. I do not know if you have changed "TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING" but when I tested your UDFs, I see that they return TIMESTAMP_NTZ values.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-type-mapping

If your query returns data with timezone information, you can use getString method instead of getObject to read the timestamp with timezone:

```
System.out.println("reading the value: " + resultSet.getString(1));
System.out.println("reading the value: " + resultSet.getString(1));

reading the value: 2021-03-02 13:40:56.873
reading the value: 2021-03-02 13:40:56.873000000 +0300
```